# perl fetchrow_array returning only the last column instead of all of the columns

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I'm working on a script called "hlstats.pl" which is a stats server from Half-Life game from http://www.hlstats-community.org/

I'm trying to run this on Strawberry perl on Windows with MySQL.

I've isolated the issue to fetchrow_array only returning whatever the last column is in the query.
Here is my modified code snippet from hlstats.pl

```
# load the options from DB
my $result = &doQuery("SELECT keyname, value FROM `${db_prefix}_Options`");
my @row;
while (@row = $result->fetchrow_array()) {
  foreach $field (@row) {
    if (defined($field)) {
      print "$field\n";
    } else {    
      print "<NULL>\n";
    }
  }
} 
##my ($keyname, $value, %oHash);
##while( ($keyname, $value) = $result->fetchrow_array ) {
##  # $oHash{$keyname} = $value;
##  print $keyname;
##  print "\n";
##}
$result->finish();
```

It will print out all the values in the column "value" if it's last and I can reverse it and it will print all the 
values in the "keyname" column if I move those around in the query.  It's not clear to me why we aren't receiving back all the columns.

This is perl, v5.10.0 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread

MySQL version 5.7.10

"perldoc perllocal" output

```
  Thu Jan 29 21:17:27 2009: "Module" ExtUtils::MakeMaker
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 6.48"

    *   "EXE_FILES: bin/instmodsh"

  Thu Jan 29 21:17:32 2009: "Module" File::Path
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 2.07"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:17:38 2009: "Module" ExtUtils::Command
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.16"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:17:47 2009: "Module" Win32API::File
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.1101"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:18:05 2009: "Module" ExtUtils::Install
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.52"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:18:10 2009: "Module" ExtUtils::Manifest
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.56"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:18:34 2009: "Module" Test::Harness
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 3.14"

    *   "EXE_FILES: bin/prove"

  Thu Jan 29 21:18:43 2009: "Module" Test::Simple
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.86"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:18:48 2009: "Module" ExtUtils::CBuilder
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.24"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:18:54 2009: "Module" ExtUtils::ParseXS
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 2.19"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:19:05 2009: "Module" version
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.76"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:19:11 2009: "Module" IO::Compress::Base
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 2.015"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:19:23 2009: "Module" Compress::Raw::Zlib
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 2.015"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:19:33 2009: "Module" Compress::Raw::Bzip2
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 2.015"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:20:34 2009: "Module" IO::Compress::Zlib
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 2.015"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:20:47 2009: "Module" IO::Compress::Bzip2
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 2.015"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:20:55 2009: "Module" Compress::Zlib
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 2.015"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:21:18 2009: "Module" Compress::Bzip2
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 2.09"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:21:24 2009: "Module" IO::Zlib
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.09"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:21:31 2009: "Module" Cwd
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 3.29"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:21:53 2009: "Module" File::Temp
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.21"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:22:03 2009: "Module" Win32::WinError
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.03"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:22:14 2009: "Module" Win32API::Registry
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.30"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:22:19 2009: "Module" Win32::TieRegistry
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.25"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:22:24 2009: "Module" File::HomeDir
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.82"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:22:29 2009: "Module" File::Which
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.05"

    *   "EXE_FILES: bin/pwhich"

  Thu Jan 29 21:22:42 2009: "Module" Archive::Zip
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.26"

    *   "EXE_FILES: bin/crc32"

  Thu Jan 29 21:22:46 2009: "Module" Package::Constants
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.02"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:22:51 2009: "Module" IO::String
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.08"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:22:59 2009: "Module" Archive::Tar
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.44"

    *   "EXE_FILES: bin/ptar bin/ptardiff"

  Thu Jan 29 21:23:04 2009: "Module" Parse::CPAN::Meta
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.04"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:23:16 2009: "Module" YAML
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.68"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:23:23 2009: "Module" Digest::MD5
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 2.38"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:23:29 2009: "Module" Digest::SHA1
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 2.11"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:23:38 2009: "Module" Digest::SHA
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 5.47"

    *   "EXE_FILES: shasum"

  Thu Jan 29 21:25:58 2009: "Module" CPAN
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.9301"

    *   "EXE_FILES: scripts/cpan"

  Thu Jan 29 21:26:05 2009: "Module" Term::ReadKey
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 2.30"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:26:09 2009: "Module" Term::ReadLine
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.0302"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:26:13 2009: "Module" Text::Glob
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.08"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:26:24 2009: "Module" URI
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.37"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:26:28 2009: "Module" HTML::Tagset
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 3.20"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:26:41 2009: "Module" HTML::Parser
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 3.59"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:27:18 2009: "Module" LWP
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 5.823"

    *   "EXE_FILES: bin/lwp-request bin/lwp-mirror bin/lwp-rget
        bin/lwp-download"

  Thu Jan 29 21:27:31 2009: "Module" LWP::Online
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.07"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:27:56 2009: "Module" Win32::File
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.06"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:28:17 2009: "Module" File::Remove
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.42"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:28:21 2009: "Module" Win32::File::Object
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.01"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:28:45 2009: "Module" Win32::API
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.58"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:29:05 2009: "Module" Params::Util
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.35"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:29:14 2009: "Module" IPC::Run3
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.042"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:29:19 2009: "Module" Test::Script
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.03"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:29:24 2009: "Module" Win32::Env::Path
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.01"

    *   "EXE_FILES: script/win32envpath"

  Thu Jan 29 21:29:46 2009: "Module" Parse::Binary
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.11"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:29:51 2009: "Module" Win32::Exe
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.11"

    *   "EXE_FILES: script/exe_update.pl"

  Thu Jan 29 21:30:32 2009: "Module" Math::BigInt
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.89"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:30:52 2009: "Module" Math::BigInt::FastCalc
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.19"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:31:14 2009: "Module" Math::BigRat
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.22"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:31:37 2009: "Module" Math::BigInt::GMP
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.24"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:31:49 2009: "Module" XML::Parser
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 2.36"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:32:18 2009: "Module" XML::NamespaceSupport
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.09"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:32:28 2009: "Module" XML::SAX
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.96"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:32:41 2009: "Module" XML::LibXML::Common
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.13"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:33:01 2009: "Module" XML::LibXML
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.69"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:33:30 2009: "Module" PAR::Dist
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.43"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:33:37 2009: "Module" PAR::Dist::FromPPD
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.03"

    *   "EXE_FILES: bin/ppd2par"

  Thu Jan 29 21:33:42 2009: "Module" PAR::Dist::InstallPPD
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.02"

    *   "EXE_FILES: bin/parinstallppd"

  Thu Jan 29 21:34:18 2009: "Module" IO::Stringy
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 2.110"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:34:41 2009: "Module" Tree::DAG_Node
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.06"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:35:03 2009: "Module" Test::Warn
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.11"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:35:21 2009: "Module" Test::Tester
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.107"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:35:27 2009: "Module" Test::NoWarnings
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.084"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:35:34 2009: "Module" Test::Deep
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.103"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:35:39 2009: "Module" DBM::Deep
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.0013"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:35:59 2009: "Module" YAML::Tiny
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.36"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:36:23 2009: "Module" AutoLoader
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 5.68"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:36:29 2009: "Module" PAR
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.984"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:36:34 2009: "Module" PAR::Repository::Query
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.12"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:36:39 2009: "Module" PAR::Repository::Client
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.21"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:36:49 2009: "Module" PPM
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.01_01"

    *   "EXE_FILES: bin/ppm.pl"

  Thu Jan 29 21:37:09 2009: "Module" Number::Compare
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.01"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:37:19 2009: "Module" pler
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.34"

    *   "EXE_FILES: script/pler"

  Thu Jan 29 21:37:44 2009: "Module" Data::Compare
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.21"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:37:50 2009: "Module" CPAN::Checksums
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 2.02"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:37:56 2009: "Module" File::chmod
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.32"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:38:01 2009: "Module" CPAN::Inject
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.11"

    *   "EXE_FILES: script/cpaninject"

  Thu Jan 29 21:38:15 2009: "Module" pip
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.13"

    *   "EXE_FILES: script/pip"

  Thu Jan 29 21:39:33 2009: "Module" DBI
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.607"

    *   "EXE_FILES: dbiproxy dbiprof dbilogstrip"

  Thu Jan 29 21:40:00 2009: "Module" DBD::SQLite
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 1.14"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "

  Thu Jan 29 21:40:20 2009: "Module" CPAN::DistnameInfo
*       "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib"

    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"

    *   "VERSION: 0.07"

    *   "EXE_FILES: "
```

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

print map "$_\n",
      DBI->available_drivers;
```

The output is:

- DBM
- ExampleP
- File
- Gofer
- Multiplex
- Proxy
- SQLite
- Sponge
- mysql

Comment: Can you try to change the `SELECT` query to something like: `SELECT 111 AS keyname, 222 AS value` to see if it will have the same issue. After that, it would also be possible for you to provide a self contained program that exhibits the issue, since there will be no reference to your actual tables.

Comment: You say in the question that the code provided is "modified" from the original program. Double-check that, in the actual program, you really do have `@row = $result->fetchrow_array`. The problem you describe sounds like what would happen if you accidentally wrote `$row = $result->fetchrow_array` instead.

Comment: Forgive me I'm struggling with the Perl.  Thank goodness for stackoverflow already!  My understanding is that `@row` is an array because it's defined with an @ instead of a $.  So wouldn't the statement:

    @row = $result->fetchrow_array()

Assign the array result to the array variable?

Comment: @tjd, `fetchrow_array` is being called in list context

Comment: Re "*Here is my modified code snippet from hlstats.pl*", No good. Provide us code that actually exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly likely that your real code has this

```
while ( $row = $result->fetchrow_array() ) {

    foreach $field ( $row ) {

        if ( defined($field) ) {
            print "$field\n";
        }
        else {    
            print "<NULL>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The [documentation for `fetchrow_array`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_array) says this

> If called in a scalar context for a statement handle that has more than one column, it is undefined whether the driver will return the value of the first column or the last. So don't do that.

I would write this

```
while ( my @row = $result->fetchrow_array ) {
    print "$_\n" for map { $_ // '<NULL>' } @row;
}
```

or you can use `fetchrow_arrayref` like this

```
while ( my $row = $result->fetchrow_arrayref ) {
    print "$_\n" for map { $_ // '<NULL>' } @$row;
}
```

It can be very hard to uncover a bug when we can't see what you see. Please be careful either to show the real source code, or something that you have tested and produces the same symptom.